# promise await throwing "RangeError: Maximum call stack size exceeded"

Tags: javascript, node.js, async-await, pug

promise awaiting is throwing this error `"RangeError: Maximum call stack size exceeded"`

the repo is this [**one**](https://github.com/Ceci007/natours) I have an Email class on **utils/email.js**

This is the class where I use the pug dependency
Please take a look at the pug.renderFile if I send just a string inside h1 it works fine but with pug it does not, what am I doing wrong the pug documentation is just like my code, please help and thanks beforehand.

```
const nodemailer = require('nodemailer');
const pug = require('pug');
const { convert } = require('html-to-text');

module.exports = class Email {
  constructor(user, url) {
    this.to = user.email;
    this.firstName = user.name.split(' ')[0];
    this.url = url;
    this.from = `Cecilia Benitez <${process.env.EMAIL_FROM}>`;
  }

  newTransport() {
    /*if (process.env.NODE_ENV === 'production') {
      // Sendgrid
      return nodemailer.createTransport({
        service: 'SendGrid',
        auth: {
         user: process.env.SENDGRID_USERNAME,
          pass: process.env.SENDGRID_PASSWORD
        }
      });
    }*/

    return nodemailer.createTransport({
      host: process.env.EMAIL_HOST,
      port: process.env.EMAIL_PORT,
      auth: {
        user: process.env.EMAIL_USERNAME,
        pass: process.env.EMAIL_PASSWORD
      }
    });
  }

  // Send the actual email
  async send(template, subject) {
    // 1) Render HTML based on a pug template
    const html = pug.renderFile(`${__dirname}/../views/email/${template}.pug`, {
      firstName: this.firstName,
      url: this.url,
      subject
    });

    // 2) Define email options
    const mailOptions = {
      from: this.from,
      to: this.to,
      subject,
      html,
      text: convert(html, {
        wordwrap: 130
      })
    };

    // 3) Create a transport and send email
    return await this.newTransport().sendMail(mailOptions);
  }

  async sendWelcome() {
    return await this.send('welcome', 'Welcome to the Natours Family!');
  }

  async sendPasswordReset() {
    return await this.send(
      'passwordReset',
      'Your password reset token (valid for only 10 minutes)'
    );
  }
};
```

[image]

Comment: It seems like you are trying to stringify/render an object that contains circular references. Don't *guess* where the problem is, look at the stack trace.

Comment: I'm not using JSON.stringify in that method if that's what you mean, I'm just passing the user object.

Comment: anyway, the stack trace says something about the node_modules and that is not my code, so what to do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

go to **views/email/baseEmail.pug** and put this instead

```
//- Email template adapted from https://github.com/leemunroe/responsive-html-email-template
//- Converted from HTML using https://html2pug.now.sh/
doctype html
html
  head
    meta(name='viewport', content='width=device-width')
    meta(http-equiv='Content-Type', content='text/html; charset=UTF-8')
    title= subject

    include _style
  body
    table.body(role='presentation', border='0', cellpadding='0', cellspacing='0')
      tbody
        tr
          td
          td.container
            .content
              // START CENTERED WHITE CONTAINER
              table.main(role='presentation')

                // START MAIN AREA
                tbody
                  tr
                    td.wrapper
                      table(role='presentation', border='0', cellpadding='0', cellspacing='0')
                        tbody
                          tr
                            td
                              // CONTENT
                              block content

              // START FOOTER
              .footer
                table(role='presentation', border='0', cellpadding='0', cellspacing='0')
                  tbody
                    tr
                      td.content-block
                        span.apple-link Natours Inc, 123 Nowhere Road, San Francisco CA 99999
                        br
                        |  Don't like these emails? 
                        a(href='#') Unsubscribe
          //- td
```